# Button inside dynamic table execute the JQuery functions only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a table with a while loop using PHP dragging data from a data base in this table I've 2 buttons one for delete the other is for editing.

HTML:

```
<div id="divCenter" class="box">
    <div style="width: 166px; position: absolute; left: 642px; top: 20px; height: 44px;">
        <img src="../../images/logo.png" width="142" height="33">
    </div>
    <div id="mainDiv">
        <div id="navi"></div>
        <div id="infoi"></div>
        <table id="hor-minimalist-b">
            <div id="bgDimmer"></div>
            <div id="divContent"></div>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Team</th>
                <th scope="col">Created By</th>
                <th scope="col">Created Date</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php while ($row = $getUsersQuery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td id="uId"><?php echo $row["uId"]; ?></td>
                    <td id="fName"><?php echo $row["fName"]; ?></td>
                    <td id="lName"><?php echo $row["lName"]; ?></td>
                    <td id="team"><?php echo $row["uTeam"]; ?></td>
                    <td id="cBy"><?php echo $row["createdBy"]; ?></td>
                    <td id="uCd"><?php echo $row["uCreateDate"]; ?></td>
                    <td><input type="button" name="uEdit" id="uEdit" value="Edit" /></td>
                    <td><a href="deleteUser.php?id=<?php echo $row["uId"] ?>"><input type="button" name="uDelete" id="uDelete" value="Delete" /></a></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

My edit button is watched by a JQuery function which triggers a pop up.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#uEdit').click(function (){
        $('#bgDimmer').toggle();
        $('#divContent').toggle().load('editUser.php');
    });
});
```

The problem is that when the table is drawn only the first row edit button will execute the function do I have to add a onclick to get this working which I really like to avoid but if needed I will.

Hope my question is clear can some one shed some light on my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the id of the element(since id has to be unique and not repeated) i would recommend to use a class for the button.

```
<td><input type="button" class="buttonClassName" name="uEdit" id="uEdit" value="Edit" /></td>
```

and the Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.buttonClassName').click(function (){
     $('#bgDimmer').toggle();
     $('#divContent').toggle().load('editUser.php');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me what I was doing wrong. But why did @Bhupesh code worked with out editing the HTML.

Comment: Your welcome! infact `$('#uEdit').click(function (){});`  This creates separate handlers for every single element that matches the selector. In this case it will stop at the first element with the id “uEdit” (handler will only be created for the first element with the id “uEdit” and the rest will be ignored). `$(document).on('click','#uEdit',function (){});`  This creates a single handler for all elements that matches your selector. therefore anytime an element of id = "uEdit" is clicked it will call the function.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation learned something I didn't knew.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click','#uEdit',function (){
        $('#bgDimmer').toggle();
        $('#divContent').toggle().load('editUser.php');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in the fact that you are generating multiple elements with the uEdit as their id. You should only ever have one element on your page for a specific id. Try the same thing using classes instead of ids

Answer (score 0):

You can try change the id="uEdit" to class="uEdit", then modify the code to $('.uEdit').click(function(){  //code }). Id means the unique element on the page

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of id in button

HTML

```
<input type="button" name="uEdit" class="uEdit" value="Edit" />
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.uEdit').click(function (){
        $('#bgDimmer').toggle();
        $('#divContent').toggle().load('editUser.php');
    });
});
```